# Identifying base record - entity history in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, architecture

I wonder which one would be better solution in my situation.

I have an asset table. I want to have history of changes in asset. So I've added two fields to my entity: StartDate and EndDate. In each update I would modify EndDate of the record, insert new one and set its StartDate. But how should I identify "base" record:

1. A RevisionNo field, which would be a PrimaryKey with Id

   ```
   +---------------+----+
   |     Asset     |    |
   +---------------+----+
   | Id            | PK |
   | RevisionNo    | PK |
   | ...Details... |    |
   | StartDate     |    |
   | EndDate       |    |
   +---------------+----+
   ```
2. A BaseRecordId field, which will be null in base record.

   ```
   +---------------+----+
   |     Asset     |    |
   +---------------+----+
   | Id            | PK |
   | ...Details... |    |
   | StartDate     |    |
   | EndDate       |    |
   | BaseRecordId  | FK |
   +---------------+----+
   ```

Which one is a better approach when I often / rarely select asset history.

Regards,
Konrad

Comment: Have you considered two separate tables - Asset and AssetHistory? Asset wouldn't need a revision number at all as it represents the current state. AssetHistory would just need the Id, details, and CreateDate.

Comment: @AndyNichols yes, I considered this. But somehow my solution appered as better one to me :) But of course I may be wrong :)

Comment: Personally I would always want my history to be versioned into a separate table, maybe even in a different database (data warehouse).  Some systems store history in the same database (e.g. Microsoft Dynamics CRM), other systems even store the current record in the history table as well but have a presentation table that can be as simple as a materialised view based on the history table.  It all depends how big your history is likely to grow and how often you are going to want to bring historical data into reports.  You may also need to consider archiving history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did it like this: we have added 3 columns PrevVersionID, NextVersionID, BaseVersionID.
Bu we had requirement like if I look at some row, I should have ability to see prev version and next version, also base version. No matter how often you read data, this approach definitely will be the fastest, because you have the key of history. In your first scenario you you will need something like `SELECT TOP 1 FROM ASSETS WHERE ID = @ID ORDER BY RevesionNo`, which will be much more slower. For me having BaseID in all history rows is natural.

Comment: well, I thought to select the newest record by `SELECT * FROM Asset WHERE Id = :id AND EndDate IS NULL`.

Comment: Yes, but how do you select base record. Your question was about base record, wasn't it?

Comment: you're right, I don't know what was I thinking about writing this :D